# How to use ConfigBuilder in Jesque to configure a Heroku redis connection?

Tags: java, heroku, redis, resque

We've got a Rails app using Resque to push jobs on the queue. The consumer of the jobs is a Java app using the Jesque client. Both apps run on Heroku. What I can't figure out is how to use [Jesque's `ConfigBuilder`](http://www.jarvana.com/jarvana/view/net/greghaines/jesque/0.9.1/jesque-0.9.1-javadoc.jar!/net/greghaines/jesque/ConfigBuilder.html) class to populate the redis connection parameters from Heroku's `REDISTOGO_URL` config var. The source documentation is pretty thin. Examples other than the default `final Config config = new ConfigBuilder().build();` would be great.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure how to do it with Jesque's `ConfigBuilder` but here is how you do it with a `JedisPool`:

```
URI redisURI = new URI(System.getenv("REDISTOGO_URL"));
JedisPool pool = new JedisPool(new JedisPoolConfig(),
    redisURI.getHost(), 
    redisURI.getPort(),
    Protocol.DEFAULT_TIMEOUT, 
    redisURI.getUserInfo().split(":",2)[1]);
```